# does account abstraction wallets have different address across different chains?

Tags: metamask, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

i was using ambire wallet  which is abstraction wallet and it have same account address across differnt chain . but i read it somewhere that abstraction account wallet have different address across different chain.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. Account Abstraction Wallets/Smart Wallets (mostly) uses [create2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) opcode, which lets you predict the wallet address before even deploying. Using this method, Account Abstraction wallet factories can create deterministic addresses across all the chains.

Comment: can you give me some example of account abstraction wallet

Comment: Ambire - https://www.ambire.com/
Sequence - https://sequence.app/wallet
Safe - https://app.safe.global/welcome